# Can I use boolean and operation between an array and a bit in verilog

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

I have an input say in which is 4 bits and defined as:
input [3:0] in;

and another input say enable which is 1 bit and defined as:
input enable;
and a wire is defined as:
wire [3:0] out_int;

and I want to get the boolean AND operation of them as:

out_int[3:0] = in[3:0] && enable;

I am not able to get the desired output,
what I want to model is,
if enable hv is 1 or 0 out_int (all 4 bits) should be equal to in (all 4 bits) , and when enable is X or Z all 4 bits of out_int should go 4'bx.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **logical and** operator `&&` whose result is 1 bit. And to check for z or x, you need use the `===` operator in Verilog, or `$isunkown()` in SystemVerilog.

What you seem to want is the conditional operator `? :`.

```
//              condition                            true   false
out_int[3:0] = (enable ===1'bx || enable === 1'bz) ? 4'bx : in[3:0];
```